# PyDrake: Center of Mass in Free-Floating Simulation is moving wihtout any (External) Forces Applied

Tags: drake

As I understand, without any application of external force (such as gravity), the center of mass of a multibody system should be constant if only internal torques (at the joints) are applied.

In PyDrake, I've set up a free-floating simulation of a box spacecraft with a 6 DoF arm attached. At the start, I set an initial velocity to the first joint using the following command:

```
plant.GetJointByName("Joint_1").set_angular_rate(plant_context, -2.5)
```

As expected, the whole multibody system is tumbling based on the inertia properties. However, while looking at the meshcat simulation, the spacecraft systems seemed to move away from the initial position. I checked the System Center of mass location using the following command:

```
print(plant.CalcCenterOfMassPosition(plant_context))
```

And indeed, the command returns different position vectors at the beginning and end of the simulation. As I understand this should not happen as no forces are applied to the system except the initial angular rate which should only introduce angular momentum to the system and not linear momentum and hence no translation of the CoM but the simulation is different than this.

I wonder if this is an artifact of the integrator being used or some other phenomenon in drake that I am missing or setting up incorrectly.

The Pastebin of the urdf file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/rUVRkBBf

The pydrake script which I'm running is here:

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()

# Adds both MultibodyPlant and the SceneGraph, and wires them together.
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0)
# Note that we parse into both the plant and the scene_graph here.
Parser(plant, scene_graph).AddModelFromFile(flairSCpath)
# Don't Weld Frame for Free-Floating Bodies.
# plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), plant.GetFrameByName("Base_SC"))
# Reduce/remove gravity
plantGravityField = plant.gravity_field()
plantGravityField.set_gravity_vector([0,0,0])
plant.Finalize()

# Adds the MeshcatVisualizer and wires it to the SceneGraph.
meshcat = ConnectMeshcatVisualizer(builder, scene_graph, zmq_url=zmq_url, delete_prefix_on_load=True)

diagram = builder.Build()
context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
plant_context = plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(context)
# plant.SetPositions(plant_context, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
plant.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(plant_context, np.zeros(6))
# plant.GetJointByName("Joint_1").set_angular_rate(context, -2.5)
plant.GetJointByName("Joint_1").set_angular_rate(plant_context, -2.5)

# Print CoM Value at the Start
print("CoM Location Before Simulation:")
print(plant.CalcCenterOfMassPosition(plant_context))

simulator = Simulator(diagram, context)
# simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)

meshcat.load()
# MakeJointSlidersThatPublishOnCallback(plant, meshcat, context);

# meshcat.start_recording()
simulator.AdvanceTo(60.0 if running_as_notebook else 0.1)
# meshcat.stop_recording()
# meshcat.publish_recording()
print("CoM Location After Simulation")
print(plant.CalcCenterOfMassPosition(plant_context))
```

The movement of CoM is present even when different timesteps are set for the integrator. My worry is that the system CoM shouldn't translate without any forces applied but it does and this means I'm probably setting up the simulation incorrectly.

Comment: I'm not actually sure.  I took a quick look, and confirmed your findings and didn't see anything obviously wrong with your code.  I agree it's unexpected behaviour.  (FTR -- I've added a missing binding here: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/14249)

Comment: Not clear to me that the CoM should sit still if you set an arbitrary joint's angular velocity. In general that could also introduce linear momentum of outboard bodies (you aren't doing it by applying internal forces but rather simply declaring that there exists a relative velocity between two bodies). I'll get a local dynamicist to take a look.

Comment: Ah.  Sherm is right.  The acceleration of your center of mass should be zero, but you probably have a non-zero velocity of your center of mass from the initial conditions.  That velocity will remain constant for the duration.

Comment: The only initial condition I set is the angular rate of Joint_1. Does this impart velocity on the center of mass due to setting relative motion between two bodies? Then maybe I misunderstand/misuse the set_angular_rate function to set an initial condition for the simulation. I can check the change in center of mass position with time to check that there are no accelerations during the simulation. Then I have to find a way to set the initial joint angular rate without adding velocity to the center of mass of the system.

Comment: In addition, I will also try adding a controller LeafSystem which connects to the joint actuation input port and applies torque at the joint (mimicking a joint controller). Then the torques/forces should be internal, not from a declared velocity. Hopefully, this results in a simple system that I am trying to simulate which is basically a tumbling satellite w/ a robot arm.

Comment: I don't think you misunderstand the API.  For any multibody system in zero G, it will have some joint positions and velocities.  By manually setting the initial velocity to be non-zero without trying hard to keep the center of mass velocity to be zero, you've produced an initial state with non-zero initial center of mass velocity.  I agree that using torques instead of velocities is the way to go -- you'll find that actuating that one joint will cause velocities in the other joints (to keep the center of mass position fixed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally, the answer is indeed from the comments to the question. The set_angular_rate() function does set the initial angular rate between two bodies but while enforcing this constraint, it also causes an initial velocity of the center of mass. A better way to move the joint to quickly test a free-floating system is by using get_actuation_input_port().FixValue() function instead. A quick example of this is given below (which has no CoM movement):

```
builder = DiagramBuilder()

# Adds both MultibodyPlant and the SceneGraph, and wires them together.
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0)
# Note that we parse into both the plant and the scene_graph here.
Parser(plant, scene_graph).AddModelFromFile(flairSCpath)
# Don't Weld Frame for Free-Floating Bodies.
# plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), plant.GetFrameByName("Base_SC"))
# Reduce/remove gravity
plantGravityField = plant.gravity_field()
plantGravityField.set_gravity_vector([0,0,0])
plant.Finalize()

# Adds the MeshcatVisualizer and wires it to the SceneGraph.
meshcat = ConnectMeshcatVisualizer(builder, scene_graph, zmq_url=zmq_url, delete_prefix_on_load=True)

diagram = builder.Build()
context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
plant_context = plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(context)
# plant.SetPositions(plant_context, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
jointAcutation =  np.zeros((6,1))
jointAcutation[0] = 1
plant.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(plant_context, jointAcutation)

# Print CoM Value at the Start
print("CoM Location Before Simulation:")
print(plant.CalcCenterOfMassPosition(plant_context))

simulator = Simulator(diagram, context)
# simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)

meshcat.load()
# MakeJointSlidersThatPublishOnCallback(plant, meshcat, context);

# meshcat.start_recording()
simulator.AdvanceTo(60.0 if running_as_notebook else 0.1)
# meshcat.stop_recording()
# meshcat.publish_recording()
print("CoM Location After Simulation")
print(plant.CalcCenterOfMassPosition(plant_context))
```

Thanks to Russ Tedrake and Sherm to help me (and future users hopefully) to understand this.

Comment: great that you figured it out!  just to be clear, this behavior is not particular to drake -- any multibody simulator will have this behavior if you set the velocity in the initial conditions.

Answer (score 2):

There is another check that there are no external forces acting on your system.
There is a C++ method (similarly in Python) whose signature is something like:

```
SpatialMomentum<T> MultibodyPlant::CalcSpatialMomentumInWorldAboutPoint(
      const systems::Context<T>& context,
      const Vector3<T>& p_WoP_W)
```

If the net external forces on your system is zero, the .translational() component of the returned spatial momentum should remain constant. This is true, regardless of what you pass in for p_WoP_W.

If there are no external forces on your system (hence the net external moment on your system is zero), the .rotational() component of the returned spatial momentum should remain constant as long as p_WoP_W is p_WoScm_W (position vector from World origin Wo to the system center of mass Scm, expressed in world W) or the zero vector.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my quick reproduction, in case it helps.  I've confirmed that setting a very small target accuracy results in the same numbers, set the initial angular velocity down so it looks more reasonable, confirmed that the gravity is properly being zeroed, etc.

```
import numpy as np
import pydrake.all
import pydot

builder = pydrake.systems.framework.DiagramBuilder()

# Adds both MultibodyPlant and the SceneGraph, and wires them together.
plant, scene_graph = pydrake.multibody.plant.AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0)
# Note that we parse into both the plant and the scene_graph here.
flair = pydrake.multibody.parsing.Parser(plant, scene_graph).AddModelFromFile("/home/russt/Downloads/flair.urdf")
# Don't Weld Frame for Free-Floating Bodies.
# plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), plant.GetFrameByName("Base_SC"))
# Reduce/remove gravity
plantGravityField = plant.gravity_field()
plantGravityField.set_gravity_vector([0,0,0])
plant.Finalize()

# Adds the MeshcatVisualizer and wires it to the SceneGraph.
meshcat = pydrake.systems.meshcat_visualizer.ConnectMeshcatVisualizer(builder, scene_graph, zmq_url="tcp://127.0.0.1:6000", delete_prefix_on_load=True)


diagram = builder.Build()
context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
plant_context = plant.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(context)
# plant.SetPositions(plant_context, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
plant.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(plant_context, np.zeros(6))
plant.GetJointByName("Joint_1").set_angular_rate(plant_context, -.25)
plant.get_actuation_input_port().FixValue(plant_context, np.zeros(6))

pydot.graph_from_dot_data(plant.GetTopologyGraphvizString())[0].write_svg("flair_topology.svg")

simulator = pydrake.systems.analysis.Simulator(diagram, context)
simulator.get_mutable_integrator().set_target_accuracy(1e-10)

# Print CoM Value at the Start
print("CoM Location Before Simulation:")
print(plant.CalcCenterOfMassPosition(plant_context, [flair]))

simulator.AdvanceTo(60.0)
print("CoM Location After Simulation")
print(plant.CalcCenterOfMassPosition(plant_context, [flair]))
```